# Hiding violations in Chrome Dev Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Starting a few versions ago, Google Chrome has started showing JS violations in the developer console. While that can be useful sometimes, more often it is just cluttering the console.

[image: Violations in dev console]

Is there a way to disable these violations?

As a side note, also since recently, the developer console no longer features checkboxes for the various types of debug output. Now you only have log levels: Verbose, Info, Warnings, Errors. I find the former method with checkboxes much more useful - is there some way (a flag?) to make them come back?

Comment: See https://crbug.com/717776 and https://crbug.com/714235. The intent of chromium developers was to make console filtering better although I fail to imagine the angle necessary to see the new behavior as an enhancement.

Comment: I agree. This is a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: If you select "Info", you get rid of the violations.  But it doesn't just show Info the way it used to. :(

Comment: @jmargolisvt. Also, if I select info to get rid of violations, I don't see the debug messages.

Comment: I'll never understand why people remove useful things. And add useless stuff (like the new plugin options display). Seriously, who thought that this "`User messages only`" checkbox was useless?

Answer (score 32):

In latest Chrome (64.0.3282.167), add the following to your "Filter" box with "All levels" selected:

```
-[Violation]
```

Not sure if any sort of Regex is supported any longer (previous versions of Chrome had a checkbox that allowed you to filter by expression), but the `-` seems to be a "don't match".

Comment: Regex are still supported, just enclose your enclose your /regex/ in slashes.

Comment: I'll never understand why people remove useful things. And add useless stuff (like the new plugin options display). Seriously, who thought that this "`User messages only`" checkbox was useless?

Comment: If, like me, you have already added other filters, add a space before this and it will work (as of Feb 2019)

Comment: Example as @marlar was suggesting: `-/Warning:\sA\s+future\s+version/` filters the following: `Warning: A future version of React will...` .  Notice that you must use `\s` to match spaces.

Answer (score 10):

[Yes, as of Chrome 58](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/devtools-release-notes):

> - The Hide violations checkbox is gone. Set the logging level dropdown
>     to Verbose to see violations.

In the following screenshot, it is set to "Info":
[image: Log level options]

Comment: Filter=Info hides console.debug() messages too.

Answer (score 9):

Another option:

1. Open [**Console Settings**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/devtools-release-notes#console) (the gear icon).
2. Check the **User Messages Only** checkbox to only show messages logged from scripts. Browser violations are hidden when this checkbox is enabled.

Chrome version: `62.0.3169.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)`

[image]

Comment: as @OlegPnk said this isnt ideal - as it hides exceptions and other errors that you'd need to see.

Comment: I'll never understand why people remove useful things. And add useless stuff (like the new plugin options display). Seriously, who thought that this "`User messages only`" checkbox was useless?

Answer (score 1):

## As of Chrome 92

### Using the Console UI

The console has now a left panel on which messages can be filtered by source and type, you can open the panel and select  **user Messages** as seen below:

[image: Filter User Messages]

Downside to this approach is that once you close the panel, the filters won't be applied anymore, so if you lack of horizontal real-state on your screen, this might not be for you.

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/reference/#browser

### Using Console Message Filters

If you want to get rid of the `[Violation] ...` and `DevTools ...` messages you can filter by `-/^\[Violation\]|DevTools/` (A negated RegExp) or just use `-[Violation] -DevTools`, apparently you can use multiple filters separated by space.

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64487267/1714951
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60729232/1714951