# Filter the Chrome console messages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-console

Is there a way to filter messages in the Chrome console?
By example, I don't want to see messages from/containing the JQMIGRATE...

Comment: I think messages from JQMIGRATE are there for a reason, and in turn, removed once you've migrated (upgraded to a newer jQuery I think?) & removed the JQMIGRATE plugin.

Comment: Since chrome 94 you can do this with a simple invert check box next to the network tab search.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77518784/6996240

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you can. Recent chrome versions allow filtering using regular expressions by enclosing the search pattern in `/.../`, previous versions had a checkbox. You can express, for instance, "not bar" by using negative lookaheads, as described here [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex)

In the picture below, I tried filtering for "not bar".

[image: Example: Filtering for "not bar"]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have storybook running and by default it prints out some messages like "message arrived at manager..." -- I tried to turn this off by typing what you showed above: /^(?!.*message).*$/ -- still all messages are shown, no effect.

Comment: You don't need to use `?!` in this case. To filter out only the word `bar`, it's enough to do `-bar` (without regexes). You can also use the `-` on a regex, for example you can do `-/foo\sbar/`.

Comment: there is an easier way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77518784/6996240

Answer (score 57):

You can negate filters by prepending with `-`. For example, `-JQMIGRATE` will exclude messages containing the string "JQMIGRATE".

Regex filters can also be negated this way. e.g. `-/^DevTools/` will exclude messages that begin with "DevTools".

*(Credit goes to Donald Duck, who suggested this in a comment on the chosen answer. I thought it was a far cleaner solution than negative lookaheads, and deserved to be elevated to a top-level answer.)*

Comment: Very useful! Is there any way to filter based on multiple words? The error message I get doesn't have a word that isn't used in other error messages. I tried to add quotes around the sentence but that didn't work for me

Comment: @Y.Gherbi in the regex, you can type `\s` to signify whitespace, `-/^DevTools\sfailed/` filters out all lines starting with "DevTools failed".

Comment: Great comment! This should be front and center

Answer (score 12):

I've found this to simple filter all console messages from extensions. This will also persist until you clear the filter. Type `-chrome-extension:`. This will REMOVE any messages that come from -> `chrome-extension:` <- urls.

You can use multiple filters by putting a space between each query. Ex. `-chrome-extension: -cookie`. Notice the space after the `:` and before the `-c`. This will REMOVE any messages that come from -> `chrome-extension:` <- urls and also REMOVE any messages with `cookie` in the context.

**Using Chrome**
    Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image: Chrome Filter Useage]

Comment: I had to add `-url:chrome-extension` to filter out all of them. So in total: `-chrome-extension -url:chrome-extension`.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer works for single line filtering, but I found it also filters out any multi-line logs.
See the following examples.

**No filter:**

> [image: No Filter]

**Accepted answer (missing multi-line logs):**

> [image: Accepted answer - missing multi-line logs]

**Fixed negative filter (correctly keeps multi-line logs):**

```
/^((.|\s)(?!Violation))+$/
```

> [image: Fixed negative filter]

**Bonus! Easy filtering out multiple matches:**

```
/^((.|\s)(?!Violation|creating))+$/
```

> [image: Bonus! Easy filtering out multiple matches]

Comment: How to mix those? For example I already have there something like: "-url:http://example.com" and now want to add a regular expression. How to do it?