# Filter out console messages in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: regex, filter, google-chrome-devtools

I have a list of 4 console log messages that appear every 2 seconds in my Dev Tools console. I'd like to filter them out but using the filtering DSL that I use for the `Network` tab doesn't seem to work

My messages are:

> [service]: failed to connect to service
>
> OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:8888/service net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What type of filter should I use to make them disappear??? I tried using rexeg, something like [^service] but it didn't seem to work...

Comment: In new Chrome you can prefix with `-` like `-service`

Comment: As I said this works in the `Network` tab but it doesn't seem to work on the `Console` tab filter input...

Comment: Like I said `-something` works only in the new Chrome (specifically, Chrome Canary).

Comment: When you said new Chrome I assumed version 50+ or something along those lines...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter the Chrome console messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130085/filter-the-chrome-console-messages)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the latest version of Chrome (^62) it finally seems to work.

I can use `-[service]` and it properly filters out the messages.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can just right click on them in the Console and filter them there like so:

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution but in the age of single js files this will also filter out everything.

Comment: @Konstantine Hmmm... That's interesting because usually for me, it only filters out those particular messages so they don't clutter up my console. I am assuming that is what you are attempting to do?

Comment: Yes but I have an all-in-one `app.js` file so I can't possible filter out every log that it produces

Comment: @Konstantine Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: +1 is there a way to filter out only one message yet? There's a new chrome version every week at the moment so maybe I missed it