# Hide errors containing a specific word from Chrome developer console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-console

I need to hide some errors (that contain "props.style"):

[image]

[image]

that are contaminating my developer console. I figure hiding them by the word will be best. I have tried adding a few regex patterns on SO such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5334825/3935156), to the filter, but they seem to hide **all** errors. How do I hide just the errors with "props.style" in them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter the Chrome console messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130085/filter-the-chrome-console-messages)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [negative filter](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#negative-filters): `-props.style`

Regular expressions also work: `-/props\.style/`

Comment: That's fantastic thank you! I also hid other errors in the same filter by just adding them without a comma, such as `-props.style -someOtherError`