# In Chrome DevTools can you filter to exclude results?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the Console tab, I have a long list of error messages that originate from a third party library that I can do nothing about.  In the `Filter` textbox, is there some way to write a filter that excludes only errors that match a filter, rather the other way round? For instance, can I filter out messages that match:

```
Material-UI: The `InputAdornment` variant infers the variant prop you do not have to provide one.
```

...and show everything else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter the Chrome console messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130085/filter-the-chrome-console-messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the filter box, the error that you are getting you just start the filter with -

For example, on one site, they were getting the error ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT to find all errors besides ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT you would just put -ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT