# How to hide Violations in Chrome 58+ while still showing console.debug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As of Chrome 58

> - The Hide violations checkbox is gone. Set the logging level dropdown
>     to Verbose to see violations.

This works, but I need to work on a project that is using `console.debug` as spammy level, while normal debug gets outputted with `log`/`info`/`warn`.

So when I actually need to read the debug, 99% of the console output is `[Violation]` clutter and I basicly need to open Firefox in order to debug properly.

Does anyone know of a workaround / extension / hack / whatever to just hide violations altogether while still showing `console.debug`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426757/786415

> Open Console Settings.
>
> Check the User Messages Only checkbox to only show messages logged
>   from scripts
>
> Browser violations are hidden when this checkbox is enabled.
>
> Chrome version: 62.0.3169.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

Noted by @red:  that this will also hide warns/errors that you didn't explicitly throw / console output - worth remembering when you see unexplained behaviour and (apparently) no errors in the console!

Comment: Awesome that they finally changed this. Sometimes you want to focus on things only _you_ can control. Changed your answer to the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Welp, I guess the only way is to use RegEx: `/^((?!\[Violation\]).)*$/` into filter box and you'll be able to show everything except violations.</strike>

Edit: This is no longer necessary, you can tick a checkbox to show "User Messages Only".