# Chrome 2019 - How to disable Verbose console messages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone know how to disable [violation] in Chrome since recent updates?
I'm currently at Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

For the record, to save you from telling me to untick the check box or type in `-[violation]`in "filter" this is what the dev tools look like:
[image]

Comment: Simply hide the left panel by clicking the first button in the console toolbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding violations in Chrome Dev Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023334/hiding-violations-in-chrome-dev-console)

Comment: no. that one is more than a year old. and the chrome interface is nothing like that anymore. All the answers are completely irrelevant for modern versions of chrome. wOxxOm's suggestions solved the problem